# Authenticating mail credential having 2-Step Verification

Tags: ios, objective-c, smtp

In iOS my application, I want to send mail using SMTP for which I'm using SKPSMTPMessage.

There is a button to validate entered mail credentials, which is working fine for normal mail verification process, but unable to validate mail credential's with **2-Step Verification**.

Is there any way to validate entered mail credential having **2-Step Verification** process on.